# How to handle a wait for element to disappear in Appium?

Tags: appium

```
ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element);
```

I am getting exceptions as:

> Unsupported command exception: isElementDisplayed

Answer (score -1):

I was searching on internet **Unsupported command Exception** comes, when something XYZ operation is not supported, so try something like this.
 Keep one `while` loop, if element is already **present and visible**, after sometime you waiting for element to vanish.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fdriver, 10);
                WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ReadExcelFiles.FindElementView(xpath)));        
                while(element.isDisplayed()) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
}
```